# Linux driver development: Difference between PCI and PCIe driver?

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver

I'm programming a PCI driver for Linux 2.6.36.

Here is my code. My question is, do I have to do some modifications if I want to use this driver for a PCIe device?

```
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/pci.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <asm-generic/signal.h>
#undef debug


// ATTENTION copied from /uboot_for_mpc/arch/powerpc/include/asm/signal.h
// Maybe it don't work with that
//____________________________________________________________
#define SA_INTERRUPT    0x20000000 /* dummy -- ignored */
#define SA_SHIRQ        0x04000000
//____________________________________________________________

#define pci_module_init pci_register_driver // function is obsoleted

// Hardware specific part
#define MY_VENDOR_ID 0x5333
#define MY_DEVICE_ID 0x8e40
#define MAJOR_NR     240
#define DRIVER_NAME  "PCI-Driver"

static unsigned long ioport=0L, iolen=0L, memstart=0L, memlen=0L,flag0,flag1,flag2,temp=0L;

// private_data
struct _instance_data {

    int counter; // just as a example (5-27)

    // other instance specific data
};

// Interrupt Service Routine
static irqreturn_t pci_isr( int irq, void *dev_id, struct pt_regs *regs )
{
    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}


// Check if this driver is for the new device
static int device_init(struct pci_dev *dev,
        const struct pci_device_id *id)
{
    int err=0;  // temp variable

    #ifdef debug

    flag0=pci_resource_flags(dev, 0 );
    flag1=pci_resource_flags(dev, 1 );
    flag2=pci_resource_flags(dev, 2 );
    printk("DEBUG: FLAGS0 = %u\n",flag0);
    printk("DEBUG: FLAGS1 = %u\n",flag1);
    printk("DEBUG: FLAGS2 = %u\n",flag2);

    /*
     * The following sequence checks if the resource is in the
     * IO / Storage / Interrupt / DMA address space
     * and prints the result in the dmesg log
     */
    if(pci_resource_flags(dev,0) & IORESOURCE_IO)
    {
        // Ressource is in the IO address space
        printk("DEBUG: IORESOURCE_IO\n");
    }
    else if (pci_resource_flags(dev,0) & IORESOURCE_MEM)
    {
        // Resource is in the Storage address space
        printk("DEBUG: IORESOURCE_MEM\n");
    }
    else if (pci_resource_flags(dev,0) & IORESOURCE_IRQ)
    {
        // Resource is in the IRQ address space
        printk("DEBUG: IORESOURCE_IRQ\n");
    }
    else if (pci_resource_flags(dev,0) & IORESOURCE_DMA)
    {
        // Resource is in the DMA address space
        printk("DEBUG: IORESOURCE_DMA\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printk("DEBUG: NOTHING\n");
    }

    #endif /* debug */

    // allocate memory_region
    memstart = pci_resource_start( dev, 0 );
    memlen = pci_resource_len( dev, 0 );
    if( request_mem_region( memstart, memlen, dev->dev.kobj.name )==NULL ) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "Memory address conflict for device \"%s\"\n",
                dev->dev.kobj.name);
        return -EIO;
    }
    // allocate a interrupt
    if(request_irq(dev->irq,pci_isr,SA_INTERRUPT|SA_SHIRQ,
            "pci_drv",dev)) {
        printk( KERN_ERR "pci_drv: IRQ %d not free.\n", dev->irq );
    }
    else
    {
        err=pci_enable_device( dev );
        if(err==0)      // enable device successful
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else        // enable device not successful
        {
            return err;
        }

    }
    // cleanup_mem
    release_mem_region( memstart, memlen );
    return -EIO;
}
// Function for deinitialization of the device
static void device_deinit( struct pci_dev *pdev )
{
    free_irq( pdev->irq, pdev );
    if( memstart )
        release_mem_region( memstart, memlen );
}

static struct file_operations pci_fops;

static struct pci_device_id pci_drv_tbl[] __devinitdata = {
    {       MY_VENDOR_ID,           // manufacturer identifier
        MY_DEVICE_ID,           // device identifier
        PCI_ANY_ID,             // subsystem manufacturer identifier
        PCI_ANY_ID,             // subsystem device identifier
        0,                      // device class
        0,                      // mask for device class
        0 },                    // driver specific data
        { 0, }
};

static int driver_open( struct inode *geraetedatei, struct file *instance )
{
    struct _instance_data *iptr;

    iptr = (struct _instance_data *)kmalloc(sizeof(struct _instance_data),
            GFP_KERNEL);
    if( iptr==0 ) {
        printk("not enough kernel mem\n");
        return -ENOMEM;
    }
    /* replace the following line with your instructions  */
    iptr->counter= strlen("Hello World\n")+1;    // just as a example (5-27)

    instance->private_data = (void *)iptr;
    return 0;
}

static void driver_close( struct file *instance )
{
    if( instance->private_data )
        kfree( instance->private_data );
}


static struct pci_driver pci_drv = {
    .name= "pci_drv",
            .id_table= pci_drv_tbl,
            .probe= device_init,
            .remove= device_deinit,
};

static int __init pci_drv_init(void)
{    // register the driver by the OS
    if(register_chrdev(MAJOR_NR, DRIVER_NAME, &pci_fops)==0) {
        if(pci_module_init(&pci_drv) == 0 ) // register by the subsystem
            return 0;
        unregister_chrdev(MAJOR_NR,DRIVER_NAME); // unregister if no subsystem support
    }
    return -EIO;
}

static void __exit pci_drv_exit(void)
{
    pci_unregister_driver( &pci_drv );
    unregister_chrdev(MAJOR_NR,DRIVER_NAME);
}

module_init(pci_drv_init);
module_exit(pci_drv_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be pertinent to call `release_mem_region` after calling `pci_enable_device`? As it stands, the memory region will still be allocated even if this call fails. Is it perhaps even just sane behaviour to use `check_mem_region` too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a software standpoint, PCI and PCI Express devices are essentially the same.  PCIe devices had the same configuration space, BARs, and (usually) support the same PCI INTx interrupts.

Example #1: Windows XP has no special knowledge of PCIe, but runs fine on PCIe systems.

Example #2: My company offers both PCI and PCIe versions of a peripheral board, and they use the same Windows/Linux driver package.  The driver does not "know" the difference between the two boards.

However: PCIe devices frequently take advantage of "advanced" features, like [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Signaled_Interrupts), Hotplugging, extended configuration space, etc.  Many of these feature existed on legacy PCI, but were unused.  If this is a device you are designing, it is up to you whether or not you implement these advanced features.

Comment: Don't forget that PCIe legacy devices (PCIe devices that act like they are PCI devices for compatibility reasons) implement an number of no longer recommended features.  The main features that come to mind are I/O reads and writes, which were found to be terribly inefficient in practice.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I remember, for the device driver I've written, there's no difference between the PCI devices and the PCIe devices. My device driver uses the same kind of calls as yours: `chrdev`, `pci_resource`, `irq`, and `mem_region`.

Comment: Hi @Peter, as I remember, PCIE devices also support MSI interrupt. So you can request MSI interrupt to save CPU cycle. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

PCIe is an advanced version with more speed and capabilities. 
The basic capabilities remains same for all standards.
The driver registration and providing the handlers is one and the same because all PCI drivers register to the same Linux PCI subsystem.